# match a partially moved enum Rust

Tags: rust, enums, match, borrow-checker

I am encountering an issue where I am consuming the contents of an enum by moving a value from it based on the a match over it. After doing this, I want to return that calculated value and also another value just based on which match the enum is. However, I am getting an error `use of partially moved value: <variable name>`. I know that I can just move everything into 1 match statement but that just isn't as clean in my more complicated case.

This is a minimum reproducible example of my issue. I want to do something like this:

```rust
enum Hand {
    TwoPair(String, String),
    ThreeOfAKind(String),
}



fn print_hand(hand: Hand) {
    let value = match hand {
        Hand::TwoPair(a, b) => a.parse::<i32>().unwrap() + b.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
        Hand::ThreeOfAKind(a) => a.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
    };
    match hand {
        Hand::TwoPair(_, _) => println!("Two pair: {}", value),
        Hand::ThreeOfAKind(_) => println!("Three of a kind: {}", value),
    }
}
```

but in order to get it to actally work right now, I would have to do something like:

```rust
fn print_hand_ugly(hand: Hand) {
    match hand {
        Hand::TwoPair(a, b) => {
            let value = a.parse::<i32>().unwrap() + b.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
            println!("Two pair: {}", value);
        }
        Hand::ThreeOfAKind(a) => {
            let value = a.parse::<i32>().unwrap();
            println!("Three of a kind: {}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

any help or tips would be appreciated. Copying the value is not possible in my situation, moving is very much the preferred case. [MRE in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=470e803c3458aa2a2c8f8cdf2ee6d228)

Comment: You should really implement [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) and use `println!("{your_hand}")` instead of rolling your own `print_hand` function.

Comment: You should stick to Rust's naming conventions for enums and enum variants: `Hand`, `TwoPair`, `ThreeOfAKind`.

Comment: This was only an example of a more complex piece of code, In that code I am not just printing out a value but passing ownership of an inner part of the enum into a function that takes advantage of having the ownership. Because of this I can not just pass references around.

Comment: [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b8bbbe6fa21f23f10ff95ee2182ad77) is much closer to what I am actually encountering.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```rs
enum Hand {
    two_pair(String, String),
    three_of_a_kind(String),
}

fn print_hand(hand: Hand) {
    let value = match &hand {
        Hand::two_pair(a, b) => a.parse::<i32>().unwrap() + b.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
        Hand::three_of_a_kind(a) => a.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
    };
    match hand {
        Hand::two_pair(_, _) => println!("Two pair: {}", value),
        Hand::three_of_a_kind(_) => println!("Three of a kind: {}", value),
    }
}
```

This compiles because match uses `&Hand` rather than consuming the value itself. This means the values inside the match arm will be `&String`. In your original example, the match statement consumes and takes overship of `hand`, thus it is no longer avaliable to be used by anything after the value.

However, since this is just a print function, we can make the entire function borrow hand and not take ownership, like so:

```rs
fn print_hand(hand: &Hand) {
    let value = match hand {
        Hand::two_pair(a, b) => a.parse::<i32>().unwrap() + b.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
        Hand::three_of_a_kind(a) => a.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
    };
    match hand {
        Hand::two_pair(_, _) => println!("Two pair: {}", value),
        Hand::three_of_a_kind(_) => println!("Three of a kind: {}", value),
    }
}
```

Your original print function steals ownership of `hand`, but making `hand` have the type `&Hand` means that a reference is given instead, so ownership is not taken.

Ownership and borrowing is well explained in the Rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html

P.S. You can easily implement the `Display` trait instead https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_display.html
This will make printing easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ref` keyword to avoid moving your strings:

```rs
enum hand {
    two_pair(String, String),
    three_of_a_kind(String),
}

fn print_hand(hand: hand) {
    let value = match hand {
        hand::two_pair(ref a, ref b) => a.parse::<i32>().unwrap() + b.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
        hand::three_of_a_kind(ref a) => a.parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
    };
    match hand {
        hand::two_pair(_, _) => println!("Two pair: {}", value),
        hand::three_of_a_kind(_) => println!("Three of a kind: {}", value),
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an alternative way to spell `match &hand` that is present in the other answer.